# Response message on ajax file upload in java

Tags: java, javascript, struts2-jquery

I need to upload multiple files from jsp. I am using $ajaxFileUPload.js to take the file to server side. I am doing my file size validation in server side for each file. I need a message on validating the file, where i face a problem. I am not able to show that message. Could someone help me in this please?

Comment: `window.alert` allows you to show messages to the user.  Without more information about your requirements and code, I'm not sure what else can be suggested.

Comment: My alert is showing "undefined" when i use it. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: function attachFile(attachUrl,removeURL,size)
{
 var path = $('#fileToUpload').val();
 var randomnumber=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1); 
 var value= "?value=" + randomnumber;
 $.ajaxFileUpload(
  {
    url:attachUrl+value,
    secureuri:false,
    fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
    success: function (response)
    {
    window.alert(response.sizeMessage);
      },
    error: function (data, status, e)
    {
     alert(e);
    }
    
  });
  
}

Comment: Edit the question, don't try to put code in comments--surely you can see that it's difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the plugin but what I have done previously in similar situation is send different markers back to the client side like for an upload the exceeds the file limit size, you can start the response back with something like 'ERROR:' and then look for this marker in the function getting the response back and then branch to a different logic. You obviously have to parse the response and look for the marker.

Looking quickly at the plugin in Github, it looks like the usage is

```
$('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
  'action': '/upload.php',
  'params': {
    'extra': 'info'
  },
  'onComplete': function(response) {
    console.log('custom handler for file:');
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  },
  'onStart': function() {
    if(weWantedTo) return false; // cancels upload
  },
  'onCancel': function() {
    console.log('no file selected');
  }
});
```

So what I think you can do is in the onComplete function something like

```
if (response.search("ERROR:") != -1){
  //error condition 
  //add your msg for the front end here
} else {
  //non error condition, continue with your regular flow
}
```

Does this make sense and relate to what you are trying to do?